How to keep the default error messages when using HttpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback?
I need to emit a log anytime my HttpClient does a certificate validation as follows:
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback += (requestMessage, certificate, x509Chain, sslPolicyError) =>
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Log emitted");

    return sslPolicyError == SslPolicyErrors.None;
};
var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);

The line sslPolicyError == SslPolicyErrors.None was taken from the docs here.
However, when I do this, I change the normal exception message that is usually emitted if the certificate is not valid (e.g. expired).
With the custom handler:
The remote certificate was rejected by the provided RemoteCertificateValidationCallback
Without the custom handler (i.e. default behavior):
The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: NotTimeValid
Is there another to hook into certificate validation without overriding the default behavior and error messages?
